# File in "datas" array from the pyinstaller "spec" file is not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

By creating the following spec file:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

face_models = [
('face_recognition_models/models/*.dat', 'face_recognition_models/models')
]

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=face_models,
             datas=[
                ('material/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml','tools'),
                ('processing/model_01_human_category.h5','tools'),
                ('icon/faceicon.ico','tools')
             ],
# MORE CODE...
```

[image]

I try to run the .exe that was created and I get the following error.

[image]

My line 69:

`self.model = load_model('tools/model_01_human_category.h5')`

I confess that I don't know what else to do...

Comment: The error I get in the dialog is about the file I reference in 'dates'.

model_01_human_category.h5

Comment: but nowhere in any of your screenshots does the word "dates" appear. It makes for a confusing title. Anyway, sounds like the script you're trying to compile relies on more than just the code - it expects a "saved model", which you need to tell pyinstaller to include.

Comment: In the 'spec' I put in the 'dates' to create the files in the new 'tools' directory, however on line 69 of my script, as described in the error dialog, it can't be found, this would be the problem.

Comment: I believe that the *.dat have worked, in the error it speaks of the .h5 file and even specifies the line, as if pyinstalle's .spec didn't generate the correct path or I did it wrong.

Comment: Can you share some more information. Which model is used first in your program `model_01_human_category.h5` or '*.dat` ?

Comment: I recommend you using ``--add-data file/path;dest/folder`` instead of manually edit spec files. It is the new feature in pyinstaller 4.3. I found that be more clear and convenient.

Comment: @Deep the `*.dat` files must be called first, as they are files from the **face_recognition** library, in this case at the beginning of the file on import.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting solution that solved the problem, follow the link: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3592

I used this script to get the correct PATH from the file that was built by the .spec

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__")))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```